# c++ calculator keeps looping

Tags: c++, loops, calculator

I made this calculator

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a, b, result;
    char operation;

    while (1) {

        cout << "Enter the calculation you want to perform (e.g: 1 + 2)\n>>";
        cin >> a >> operation >> b;

        switch(operation)
        {
            case '+':
                result = a + b;
                break;

            case '-':
                result = a - b;
                break;

            case '*':
                result = a * b;
                break;

            case '/':
                result = a / b;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "\nInvalid operation. Program terminated." << endl;
                return -1;
        }

        cout << "= " << result << "\n" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's supposed to keep asking the same question and terminate if you enter something invalid.

If you enter something invalid the first time it terminates. But if you enter a valid operation and the second time you enter a invalid character it keeps outputting the same question + answer that it handled before the invalid character.

Comment: Give an example. What did you type?

Comment: This it what it does:   Enter the calculation you want to perform (e.g: 1 + 2)
>>1 + 2
= 3

Enter the calculation you want to perform (e.g: 1 + 2)
>>x
= 2

Enter the calculation you want to perform (e.g: 1 + 2)
>>= 2

Enter the calculation you want to perform (e.g: 1 + 2)
>>= 2

Enter the calculation you want to perform (e.g: 1 + 2)
>>= 2  etc..

Comment: Learning to use a debugger is a great thing to do.

Comment: @Roemerdt What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: Maybe because you are not resetting the a, b, result and operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, when a stream fails to read something, it will set its internal failbit on and it will leave the input it could not parse untouched. So, when you provide the input `"x = 2"` to your code and then try to read x as an integer, the reading fails and x remains in. Whatever happens afterwards will probably be wrong, and it will be wrong in many different ways depending on an input.

To defend against that, check whether the input succeeded:

```
    cin >> a >> operation >> b;

    if (!cin) {
        cout << "Wrong input format. Program terminated.\n";
        return -1;
    }
```

In your particular case, the particular behaviour you was getting was because you did not reinitialise your variables at every iteration of the loop. If you did that, your application would fail in some different fashion, but nonetheless, the best way out is to actually check whether the input was in the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

that's because of "operation" var is out of the "while" scope, i.e the last value is verified and the default body on the switch is never verified

Comment: Just a bunch of english words one after the other... without any coherence. Could someone decypher this?

Comment: sorry, it's not my first language

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what I meant was that the operation variable is outside the scope of the while loop so the verification of the switch compared to the last saved value in this variable

Comment: @KarolyHorvath , operation is outside the scope of the while-loop

Comment: @KarolyHorvath , ok, whatever you say, to get along with you, operation var is on a global level to the while loop, It is more or less what I was saying

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the line

```
operation=0;
```

right after the `while(1)` will do the job of terminating when an invalid answer is provided.

However, this doesn't explain why without it, the program skips asking for an operation and keeps outputting the previous result when an invalid answer is provided.